# Pandas categorical variables encoding for regression (one-hot encoding vs dummy encoding)

Tags: regression, scikit-learn, pandas, categorical-data, encoding

Pandas has a method called get_dummies() that creates a dummy encoding of a categorical variable. Scikit-learn also has a OneHotEncoder that needs to be used along with a LabelEncoder. What are the pros/cons of using each of them? Also both yield dummy encoding (k dummy variables for k levels of a categorical variable) and not one-hot encoding (k-1 dummy variables), how can one get rid of the extra category? How much of a problem does this dummy encoding create in regression models (collinearity issues - a.k.a. dummy variable trap)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One advantage of `get_dummies` is that it can operate on values other than integers (so you don't need the `LabelEncoder`) and returns a DataFrame with the categories as column names. Also, you can conveniently drop one redundant category using `drop_first=True`.

One advantage of scikit-learn's `OneHoteEncoder` lies in the scikit-learn API. OHE gives you a transformer which you can apply to your training and test set separately if you specify the total number of categories. This doesn't work with `get_dummies` ,for example, if the training set misses categories present in the test set.

You can still delete categories by simply deleting columns from the resulting numpy array (e.g. using `n_values_` or `feature_indices_` to see which columns correspond to the same feature). Some models work regardless, for example tree-based models. Also, L1 regularization can often set redundant features to zero (see [Lasso regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics))).

Comment: can you provide link with usage info for "e.g. using  n_values_ or feature_indices_" I am unable to find anything useful

Comment: They used to be attributes of the fitted OneHoteEncoder object. They have now been deprecated. All I was trying to say is you can remove a column using the column number of the feature. With `pandas` you can also use `get_loc` if you only know the feature name.

Comment: I actually resolved problem by simply adding drop_first=True in pd.get_dummies(data=X, drop_first=True) as you suggested. Exploring shape of X after I saw that 3 columns were missing for 3 categorical variables. Linear regression worked fine after that. Thank you!